# Custom Quip Live App cannot be added in a document in Quip Desktop on Windows

Tags: quip, liveapps

How to add a custom Quip Live App in a document in Quip Desktop on Windows? My app is not showing in the list of available app when I type the @ sign. It works perfectly well in the Quip web app. How can I make available my Quip Live App in Quip Desktop? Thanks